# Cant add multiple values for same key at same time

Tags: iphone, core-data, entity

{
NSManagedObject *newVehicleCategory = [NSEntityDescription
                                               insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Vehicle"
                                               inManagedObjectContext:context];

```
    [newVehicleCategory setValue:@"Car" forKey:@"category"];
    [newVehicleCategory setValue: @"Bus" forKey:@"category"];
    [newVehicleCategory setValue: @"Tractor" forKey:@"category"];
```

}

I am doing this operation in viewDidLoad of my app to add 3 vehicle categories into attribute named "category" of entity "vehicle".
But only last value is added into it, but I want all these 3 values to be entered into attribute "category".
So what should I do ??

Comment: Why do you think it should work? What have you tried so far? Where have you searched for a solution?

Comment: you can not set multiple values for same key like this because it replaces previous values with new value. If you need to set then use array and assign that array for that key.

Comment: But I need to store these 3 values as separated for future use, so what should I do ??

Comment: You have 2 ways: 1) Use 3 different keys, one per category 2) Create an array/dictionary and save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, you need three categories.

```
for (NSString *category in @[@"Car", @"Bus", @"Tractor"]) {
   NSManagedObject *newVehicleCategory = [NSEntityDescription
       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Vehicle"
       inManagedObjectContext:context];
   [newVehicleCategory setValue:category forKey:@"category"];
}
```

This seems like basic programming (pre 101). Maybe you should not get into Core Data at this point.